# facebook android sdk 4.0 , way to unregister callback from LoginManager

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using the facebook sdk 4.0 inmy android app. 
I have an Activity whose functionality is to post some message to facebook ( this is not my main Activity of my app )
i am doing the following to login to facebook and then post the message

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,  
    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    //Login is successfull, now post the message.
                }

    });
```

questions is, How do i unregister this callback from LoginManager ? i didnt find any method in LoginManager to do so.

Any reason why the sdk is designed in such way that it doesnt provide option to unregister ?

Problem is, if my activity gets destroyed and recreated ( say, due to device rotation) , the LoginManager would always have a reference to my previous activity instance which is not right.

i would like to unregister in the onDestory of the activity.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you faced with this on practice? Cause SDK is constructed to handle those situations, with memory leaks. From my expirience, SDK is working fine with activity lifecycle, and don't need to unregister callbacks.

Comment: why do you let your activity to recreate on screen rotation, use " android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" " in your activity tag of manifest file to stop the activity recreation on device rotation, just adjust the activity layout in function onConfigurationChanged

Answer (score 3):

The LoginManager does not hold a reference to your callback, the callback manager does. As long as you keep the callback manager 1-1 with the activity, your callback will be garbage collected fine.

Comment: But what if somehow I would like to register callback manager in multiple activities? Somehow this will cause NullPointerException.

Comment: You should create a callback manager per activity. Their lifetimes should be 1-1.