# How to abstract away Facebook login from an activity instance?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm designing an app with a client which is completely independent of activities/contexts. My app also needs a `login with Facebook` mechanism. I can pass an activity for that purpose, but I want to keep my callback manager independent of any activities. What would be a best practice for that? I've seen [facebook android sdk 4.0 , way to unregister callback from LoginManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121185/facebook-android-sdk-4-0-way-to-unregister-callback-from-loginmanager) but it recommends to keep the client and login activity closely tight, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. How do I create a callback on the fly, independent of any activity, and tie it to just one specific Facebook login call?

Comment: i tried on that sometime ago, the issue was a call to `onActivityResult()` is needed from the login manager, so it will remain connected to the activity, i am not sure if there is a way to do it.

Comment: Are you OK with using Fragments? You can create a login Fragment that gets added to different activities you may have, and then the Fragment itself can handle the onActivityResult and the callback management.